# Como desenvolver uma aplicação independente de frameworks?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, software

Recentemente, não me lembro onde, vi uma estrutura de aplicação na qual o *core* da aplicação, ou seja, suas entidades principais, regras de negócio etc., residiam entre as **dependências** do projeto.

Esse projeto, sim, era o executável da aplicação – que podia ser em um determinado framework, como por exemplo Zend Framework 2 ou Symfony2 (no caso do PHP, mas poderia ser aplicado a qualquer linguagem de programação).

Eu gostaria de saber mais sobre esse paradigma de desenvolvimento, se é válido em termos de desenvolvimento, e como posso começar a desenvolver assim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Por que eu deveria usar um framework?

Um framework não é absolutamente necessário: é "apenas" uma das ferramentas que está disponível para ajudá-lo a desenvolver melhor e mais rápido!

Melhor, porque um framework fornece a certeza de que você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação que está em total conformidade com as regras de negócio, que está estruturada, e que seja tanto de fácil manutenção quanto atualizável.

Mais rápido, porque ele permite aos desenvolvedores economizar tempo reutilizando módulos genéricos, a fim de se concentrar em outras áreas. Sem, no entanto, nunca ficar amarrado ao próprio framework.

### Investir na tarefa, não na tecnologia

Este é o princípio básico de um framework: Não ter que reinventar a roda. E acabar com previsões, tarefas de baixo valor agregado (por exemplo, o desenvolvimento de componentes genéricos), a fim de concentrar totalmente nas regras de negócio.

Como exemplo, um framework irá salvar o programador de ter que passar 2 ou 3 dias criando um formulário de autenticação (que não é uma tarefa específica). O tempo que é economizado pode ser dedicado à componentes mais específicos, bem como, aos testes unitários correspondentes, proporcionando código de alta qualidade, sustentável e sólido.

### Atualização e manutenção garantida

A longo prazo, um framework garante a longevidade das suas aplicações. Se uma equipe de desenvolvimento trabalhar como bem desejar, somente esta equipe, em particular, será capaz de manter e atualizar a aplicação com facilidade. Esta é a forma que um editor suporta uma solução proprietária.

Por outro lado, a estrutura que um framework proporciona à aplicação torna possível evitar essa armadilha completamente e proporciona à qualquer desenvolvedor - tendo ele participado de seu desenvolvimento ou não - a habilidade de facilmente "adotar" uma aplicação, para mantê-la ao longo do tempo e atualizá-la de forma rápida e limpa, sempre que necessário.

[image]

## Prós

### Eficiência

Tarefas que normalmente levariam horas e centenas de linhas de código para escrever, agora pode ser feito em questão de minutos com funções pré-construídos. O desenvolvimento torna-se muito mais fácil, por isso, se é mais fácil, é mais rápido e, consequentemente eficiente.

### Segurança

Um framework amplamente utilizado tem grandes implementações de segurança. A grande vantagem é a comunidade por trás dele, onde os usuários se tornam testadores ao longo prazo. Se você encontrar uma vulnerabilidade ou uma falha de segurança, você pode ir para o site do framework e deixar a equipe saber, para que eles possam corrigir.

### Custo

A maioria dos frameworks populares são gratuitos, e uma vez que também ajuda o desenvolvedor a codificar mais rápido, o custo para o cliente final será menor.

### Suporte

Como qualquer outra ferramenta distribuída, um framework geralmente vem com documentação, uma equipe de suporte, ou grandes fóruns da comunidade onde você pode obter respostas rápidas.

## Contras

### Você aprende o framework, não a linguagem

Eu acredito que este seja o maior problema. Se você estiver usando um framework e você sabe muito pouco sobre a linguagem por trás disso, você vai aprender o framework e não a própria linguagem de programação.

### Limitação

O comportamento do core de um framework não pode ser modificado, o que significa que quando você usa um framework, você é forçado a respeitar seus limites e trabalhar da forma que for necessário.

### Código é público

Uma vez que o framework está disponível para todos, ele também está disponível para pessoas com más intenções. Ele pode ser estudado a fim de saber como as coisas funcionam e para encontrar falhas que podem ser usadas contra você.

## Conclusão

Concluímos que utilizar um framework ou não, é uma opção que deve ser analisada para cada projeto, analisar se os prós e contras da utilização de um framework pode se encaixar com o que é necessário para construção e manutenção do software. Lembrando que quando falamos em tecnologia, tudo é um trade-off, um jogo onde você tira de uma parte para entregar a outra que é mais interessante para o resultado final.

Comment: Muito boa a sua resposta, concordo e discordo quanto a questão do `Código é público`, isso é ótimo para encontrar vulnerabilidades, quanto a questão da limitação essa semana pensei nisso, porque estou utilizando bastante os frameworks sem conhecer em si a linguagem. +1

Comment: Concordo, mas acaba entrando no mesmo contexto de prós e contras, mas de um modo geral o Código é público é uma boa. Eu só inseri no contras pelo o contexto de vulnerabilidade.